# want to get value of a variable from text file, concatenate it with other variables and insert the new value in new text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm doing the code like

```
echo on
SET /P CONTROLSTRING_0326 = < sample.txt
rem sample.txt has data as 00000000000000000000000000000000000002017060000000000000000

ECHO %CONTROLSTRING_0326%
pause
SET CONTROL_DATE = %CONTROLSTRING_0326:~39,6%
ECHO %CONTROL_DATE%
PAUSE
SET filler1="2226 0000000 00000000000 00000000000 
SET filler2= CONTROL 06.30"
PAUSE
SET "FINAL_CONTROL_2460 = %filler1%%CONTROL_DATE%%filler2%"
SET FINAL_CONTROL_2460
pause
SET FINAL_CONTROL_2460 > new_control.txt
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I want the file new_control.txt should have data as below

```
2226 0000000 00000000000 00000000000 201706 CONTROL 06.30"
```

but I'm getting data as 'echo is on' in new_control.txt.
Not sure what's is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there should not be space characters before the `=` in a SET command. What you have created is a variable named "CONTROL_DATE " and not "CONTROL_DATE".

Change

```
SET /P CONTROLSTRING_0326 = < sample.txt
SET CONTROL_DATE = %CONTROLSTRING_0326:~39,6%
SET "FINAL_CONTROL_2460 = %filler1%%CONTROL_DATE%%filler2%"
```

to

```
SET /P "CONTROLSTRING_0326=" < sample.txt
SET "CONTROL_DATE=%CONTROLSTRING_0326:~39,6%"
SET "FINAL_CONTROL_2460=%filler1%%CONTROL_DATE%%filler2%"
```

Comment: Thanks @lit , i'm able to write to the file but the output is as follows   "2226 0000000 00000000000 00000000000 ~39,6 CONTROL 06.30"   The sub string is not working. i want date 201706 instead of ~39,6 in file.  SET CONTROL_DATE = %CONTROLSTRING_0326:~39,6%  
 should return 201706.

Comment: Remove or comment out `echo off` to see what is happening.